# CNG SSL Provider Functions - how are they called?

Tags: windows, ssl, winapi

I've been studying the various cryptographic APIs on Windows, and the flow that Windows goes through when an application creates an SSL connection.

One of the APIs I've come across are the [CNG SSL Provider Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-ssl-provider-functions) (e.g., SslExportKey, SslImportKey, SslGenerateMasterKey, etc.). Many of these APIs require the caller to pass an SSL protocol provider in the first argument.

My question is, are these APIs only ever called by Windows during an SSL connection (I've noticed lsass.exe calls a few of them)? Or, is it possible for any application to call them, and if so, how would such application obtain a handle to the SSL protocol provider? I've noticed there is [NCryptOpenStorageProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptopenstorageprovider), however, none of the provider names refer to an SSL one. I guess what I'm trying to find out is if these APIs can ever be called outside of an SSL connection context.

My other question is, are these SSL APIs only called after Windows verify that the SSL certificate is valid?

Comment: Uh, `SslOpenProvider()`?

Comment: yes, this api is called during an SSL connection if code use it direct or via `SCHANNEL.DLL`.  usually we call it indirect. app call `InitializeSecurityContext` or `DecryptMessage` from `Secur32` or `sspicli` dll thay call `SCHANNEL` and it call ssl provider, by default - `ncryptsslp.dll`

Comment: *are these SSL APIs only called after Windows verify that the SSL certificate is valid?* no of course. it called from begin for all ssl processing

Comment: Thanks @RbMm. So does windows actually call SslGenerateMasterKey before verifying validity of server certificate?

Comment: @Kakalokia who is must/will verifing ? i dont understand sense of your question.

Comment: @RbMm During SSL connection there will be a validation step to verify that the server certificate is valid. My question is if this verification step happens before the sslprovider.h functions are called, or after.

Comment: of course sslprovider functions are called **before**, or how is possible get certifact at all ? and check of certificat is optional step

Comment: Thanks @RbMm. Does that mean if for example SslGenerateMasterKey is called, the public key parameter may not necessarily point to a trusted public key? Can these functions be called with untrusted data? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: sorry, i complete not understand your questions

Comment: @RbMm if you look at SslGenerateMasterKey, you'll see there is a parameter named hPublicKey. My assumption is that hPublicKey is the public key of the server (extracted from server certificate). My question is if this assumption is correct, or can hPublicKey be any public key (including untrusted ones).

Comment: i anyway dont understand sense of your question. i think `SslGenerateMasterKey` called only from server side (or if mutual auth used). because only server have private key. `hPublicKey`  of course can not be any key but must corresponded to `hPrivateKey` key. and so what ?

Comment: SslGenerateMasterKey is definitely called from client side based on testing I've done. Appreciate I may not be getting the point across, but the question is simply whether the hPublicKey is guaranteed to be a certificate public key, or whether it can be just any randomly generated public key.

Comment: *is definitely called from client side based on testing I've done* - and ? what is test was ? you set bp on this call ? what is call stack ? you call this api by self ? usually it called from `CSsl3TlsClientContext::GenerateServerHelloResponse`. anyway that api take private key as param suggest that this is server side api. *question is simply* - what sense in this question ? you call this api by self ? if no, why you at all ask about this ? i think that hPublicKey must corresponded to hPrivateKey key. but in what your actual problem ?